# How to keep the android screen size?

Tags: android

When my android phone is landscape,the screen size change,how to stop it?I kown that had edit manifest "configChanges",activity not start itself life again,but the display size had chang.

Comment: do you want to disable rotation of your activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add in `AndroidManifest.xml` in `activity` tag:

```
 <activity
            android:name="MyActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` to the  element/s in the manifest . This will solve your problem. Or if you want your activity in always landscape mode you can add `android:screenOrientation="landscape"`

Comment: hmm. Commented at the same time